# displaying data nested within objects - angular

Tags: html, angular, mongodb

I'm trying to display data within my dataset on my angular front end. Some info i want to display is nested within an Object Object. As you can see below. I'm having trouble displaying the lat and long values. I have tried this html:

```
                <ng-container *ngFor="let geometry of trail?.geometry">
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let location of geometry?.location">
                        <ng-container *ngFor="let lat of location?.lat">
                                {{ lat }}
                        </ng-container>
                    </ng-container>
                </ng-container>
```

[image]

Comment: What is the trouble? Could you show the data example. It's not clear, why you use ngFor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you need to display the lat in the html, but in your code you are trying to iterate an object and that is not possible in this case, for display the lat in your html you only need to access to the key lat in your object, like this:

```
<ng-container>
            {{ geometry.location.lat }}
 </ng-container>
```

If you need to show the ng-container when the lat have a value, you need to validate with *ngIf.

I hope this can be useful for you.